# Python - Behavior of `statistics.stdev()` on Numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy, statistics

I have a Numpy array and I would like to use `statistics.stdev()` to compute its standard deviation. The output of this operation is somewhat unexpected.

```
import numpy as np
from statistics import stdev, pstdev

>>> a = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3])
>>> stdev(a)
1.0
```

This is neither the sample standard deviation

```
>>> stdev([0, 1, 2, 3])
1.2909944487358056
```

nor the population standard deviation

```
>>> pstdev([0, 1, 2, 3])
1.118033988749895
```

I wonder if `statistics.stdev()` is not supposed to work with Numpy arrays or there is some underlying mechanism causing this behavior?

Note that `np.std()` works both on lists and Numpy arrays.

```
>>> np.std([0, 1, 2, 3])
1.118033988749895
>>> np.std(np.array([0, 1, 2, 3]))
1.118033988749895
```

Both give the population standard deviation as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because the `type` of numbers, type of numbers in the `list` is `float64` but the type of numbers in `numpy.array` is `int64` you can get what you get with the `list` with change `dtype` in `NumPy.array` to `float64` like below:

```
>>> a = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3])
>>> a.dtype
dtype('int64')
>>> statistics.stdev(a)
1.0

>>> a = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3], dtype=float)
>>> a.dtype
dtype('float64')
>>> statistics.stdev(a)
1.2909944487358056

>>> statistics.stdev([0, 1, 2, 3])
1.2909944487358056
```